# Any benefit in buying "ordinær" train ticket for Norwegian lokaltog in advance?

Tags: trains, norway

For NSB lokaltog such as Trondheim Lufthavn–Lademoen, is there any benefit to buy tickets in advance?  At nsb.no there is only Ordinær togbillett (no Minipris), and there don't seem to be seat reservations either.  Can I buy exactly the same ticket for the same price from a ticket machine at the train station?

Comment: Will buying a ticket at the station put you at risk of waiting for fumbling tourists to complete their transaction and then the conductor blowing their whistle before you get your turn at the machine?

Comment: @Eric Unlikely, I have 1 hour 14 minutes between flight and train.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure you will travel that day, you can buy train tickets online. That will help you if your flight is late and/or there is a queue at the ticket machine but may cost you if your flight is delayed beyond arriving that day.

So it will turn out whether you are willing to bet the money against the chance of a small or long delay and the chances of getting your train or an alternative one.

Comment: Finally, I finished buying my ticket about 5 seconds before the train left, but as the flight arrived early and immigration & luggage collection went very smoothly through arrivals I actually took the train an hour earlier than I had planned (and was not aware there was also an express bus departing every 10 minutes, but at a much higher price and longer journey).